# Pipe ffmpeg output to other process

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

I want to pipe ffmpeg output to some other process like this:
`ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 - | process`. I get `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument`. How do I achieve piping?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to provide the format with `-f`, such as:

```
ffmpeg … -f matroska - | process
```

- For a list for available formats see `ffmpeg -formats`.
- Note that some formats (typically MOV), require the output protocol to be seekable, so they will fail with the pipe output protocol.
- Also see [FFmpeg Documentation: Pipe Protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe).

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg can't infer the desired output format in this case, output format must be explicitly specified before `-` using `-f fmt` (replace `fmt` with what format is desired).

```bsh
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f fmt - | process
```

Comment: The other answer provides `-f fmt`.  In fact, the question already has a `-f fmt`.  Can you provide a reference on the “nut” protocol and describe how it is better than Matroska? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: `nut` is better than `matroska` in the sense that `nut` is a low overhead container (or atleast claimed), but `matroska` has more support across programs than `nut`. @Scott